# Web Intelligence - Countifs

Tags: business-objects, webi

I am trying to use an excel like 'Countifs' function in Business Objects, but it always outputs 1 which is incorrect.  How do I replicate this to Business Objects?

```
=IF(COUNTIFS('TabOne'!A:A,[@[Account Number]],'TabOne'!H:H,[@[Order Date]],'TabOne'!D:D,[@[Employee ID]])>0,1,0)
```

Here is my attempt in Business Objects...

```
=Count(If
([TabOne].[Account Number]=[TabTwo].[Account Number])
 And 
([TabOne].[Order Date] = [TabTwo].[Order Date])
And 
([TabOne].[Employee ID] = [TabTwo].[Employee ID]) > 0 Then 1 Else 0)
```

Comment: Not an expert, but compared to Excel formula it looks like the `> 0` condition is only applying to the latest test. Does it work if you remove some of the parenthesis `(` and `)` to only keep the one after `if (...` and before the `... ) > 0` condition?

Comment: Tried removing the parenthesis and get the same result.  Not sure if im only checking one value in each table instead of one TabOne value against the entire TabTwo table

Comment: Are TabOne and TabTwo different queries? If so, it seems like you need to create variables for concatenation of each of your set of 3 objects from each query and then merge on that and count the ones that match.